# How to map java-client of appium into my current project(non-mvn project)

Tags: appium

Can anyone provide me the steps to follow to map java client of appium into current project(non mvn project).

For Selenium web driver:- We have to download the jar from selenium site and configure it through build path.

So for java-client what is the process?

Answer (score 1):

Add the Selenium jars as you do, and along with that add the jar from following link too:

https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/target/java-client-1.2.0.jar?raw=true